# RTF Conversion Using Powershell/Word optimization

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert 90K RTFs to PDFs using MS Word. I am using a Powershell script to find all the RTFs in a directory and invoking MS Word to convert the file programmatically. The script runs really slow. I am looking for some advice on optimizing the code below.

```
Function Log-Message([String]$Message)
{
    Add-Content -Path "C:\Log\Log.txt" $Message
}

$SourceDirectory = "D:\Documents\RTF2\"
$DestinationDirectory = "D:\Documents\ConvertedRTFs\"

#Get a list of Files
Write-host "Loading Files"
$files = Get-ChildItem $SourceDirectory -Include *.rtf -Recurse
$FileName = ""

try {
    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
    
        #Get File Name
        $FullName = (Get-Item $file).FullName;
        $FileName = (Get-Item $file).Name;
        $FinalFileName = $DestinationDirectory + $FileName.Substring(0, $FileName.Length - 3) + "pdf"
        $formatPDF = [ref] 17
     
        #Check if file exists
        if(!(Test-Path $FinalFileName))
        {
            try {
                #Setup Work Application Object
                $word = new-object -ComObject "word.application"
                
                Write-host $FileName        
                
                #Convert to PDF
                $doc = $word.documents.open($FullName)
                $doc.SaveAs($FinalFileName, $formatPDF)
                $doc.Close()
            }    
            catch {
                Write-host $_.Exception.Message
                Log-Message "Error for file: " +  (Get-Item $file).Name
                Log-Message $_.Exception.Message
            }  
            finally {
                ps winword | kill   
            }
        }
        
    }
}
catch {
    Write-host $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: 1. replace `-Include *.rtf` with `-Filter *.rtf`.     2. `Get-ChildItem $SourceDirectory -Include *.rtf -Recurse | Foreach-Object {}` instead of saving then looping.      2.2. that depends on a number of things, but using the `-Parallel` parameter with `ForEach-Object might improve the efficiency by a lot as it would cause multiple files being converted at the same time. How much improvment, if any, would depend on the machine, might even cause a degradation in performance.

Comment: You're launching 90000 instances of Word - no wonder it's slow :) Move `$word = new-object -ComObject "word.application"` up out of the loop and reuse it instead

Comment: I'd honestly look for a native dotnet rtf-to-pdf library rather than automate Word, especially if you're planning on running multiple parallel instances and processing circa 100k files - it's just not designed for any of those scenarios - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/integration/considerations-unattended-automation-office-microsoft-365-for-unattended-rpa. The ongoing cost of supporting, troubleshooting and maintaining a Word automation script will be much higher than a one-off fee for a license for a proprietary third party library...

Answer (score 1):

You might need to open and save 90K documents, but you only need *one* instance of Word to do that serially.

Instantiate the Word object before entering the loop, then move the `finally` cleanup block to the outer `try` block:

```
function Log-Message([string]$Message) {
    Add-Content -Path "C:\Log\Log.txt" $Message
}

$SourceDirectory = "D:\Documents\RTF2\"
$DestinationDirectory = "D:\Documents\ConvertedRTFs\"

# Get a list of Files
Write-host "Loading Files"
$files = Get-ChildItem $SourceDirectory -Include *.rtf -Recurse

try {
    # Setup Word Application Object, we'll reuse this for all documents
    $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        # Construct destination file path 
        $destinationPath = Join-Path $DestinationDirectory ($file.BaseName,'pdf' -join '.')
        $formatPDF = [ref] 17
     
        # Check if file exists
        if (!(Test-Path $destinationPath)) {
            try {
                Write-host $file.Name
                
                # Convert to PDF
                $doc = $word.Documents.Open($file.FullName)
                $doc.SaveAs($destinationPath, $formatPDF)
                $doc.Close()
            }    
            catch {
                Write-host $_.Exception.Message
                Log-Message "Error for file: $($file.Name)"
                Log-Message $_.Exception.Message
            }
        }
    }
}
catch {
    Write-host $_.Exception.Message
}  
finally {
    Get-Process -Name winword | Stop-Process -Force   
}
```